# Am I over-complicating this? (CQRS, Domain Events, and Command Failures)

Tags: c#, cqrs, domain-events

I'm working on a CQRS framework with domain events and I'm coming across a code smell that I would like some advice on.

I'm NOT using event sourcing (ES). ES events are not the same as domain events. A domain event is interesting to the domain and may result in new commands being issued. An ES event is interesting to the persistence store. An ES event may also be a domain event, but not all ES events are domain events.

The root of my problems lies in the statement:

> A domain event… may result in new commands…

Specifically, what happens when one of *those* commands fails.

In the CQRS articles that I've read, they say that the application layer is responsible for validating a command before it is ever sent to the command bus.
I don't agree with this for two reasons. 1) I don't trust the client (security spoofing). 2) As the application matures and new events/handlers/commands are added, validation of Command A may not know that it also needs to validate Command Foo.

So, the application layer needs to know if a command was successful or not. And if it failed, the application layer needs some information explaining why. But with commands triggering events which issue new commands which trigger events… I end up with response classes looking like this:

```
public interface ICommandResponse
{
    ICommand OriginatingCommand { get; set; }
    bool Successful { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ICommandResponse> DerivativeCommands { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IEventResponse> EventResponses { get; set; }
}

public interface IEventResponse
{
    IEvent OriginatingEvent { get; set; }
    bool Successful { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IEventHandlerResponse> EventHandlerResponses { get; set; }
}

public interface IEventHandlerResponse
{
    string Descriptor { get; set; } // TODO: A way to identify the event handler.
    bool Successful { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Exception> Exceptions { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ICommandResponse> DerivativeCommands { get; set; }
}
```

All I want is to be able to tell if a command succeeded or failed, and if it failed, why. I ended up with this recursive tree structure. Am I over-complicating this?

Comment: Yeah; looks way over complicated. Not *everything* has to be so generic. I'm not sure exactly what to recommend for you though.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens when one of those commands fails

So in the usual context for domain events, the answer is that the entire transaction fails.

> All I want is to be able to tell if a command succeeded or failed, and if it failed, why.

How that information gets back to the caller depends on your code style -- you could throw an exception, or return some sort of `Either` data type, or notify a callback handler, or...

If the caller is in another process, you are going to need to turn the internal options into a message of some sort.  A success/failed status with a optional reason field will get you enough experience to figure out what you want to include in the schema of your next release.

Comment: This means that the domain event handlers need to be executed in the same transaction as the changed that triggered that domain event. Is this right?
How do you do this if you use a document database without transactions?